# How to solve the ZeroDivisionError: division by zero /neat-python?

Tags: python, zero, divide-by-zero, neat

Can someone point out to me why I get the division by zero error in the neat-python module when I set the default config file's "pop_size" to 1, the division error is given for the

```
neat/mathutil.py in mean, 
----> 9     return sum(map(float, values)) / len(values), 
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero.
```

If I set pop_size to anything above 1, there's no error but I do occasionally get a muddle up in my results as I've written my code to only run 1 genome at a time which is what I need.

In advance thank you very much for your time, I'm looking forward with your replies.

Comment: This sounds like a bug report that should be filed on github

Comment: It could be more helpful if you showed your code.

Comment: @MadPhysicist where do i find the published bug report

Comment: The error is not here. The array you pass in is empty. Can you provide a proper mcve and full stack trace? I can probably provide a patch if you do.